# Email fires before the custom order item attribute is saved by magento observer

Tags: magento

I am facing a problem while saving Magento custom variable on order item table by observer.

The Email fires before the custom attribute is saved on the table by magento observer sales_order_place_after. But after the order place I login in admin panel and click on the send mail button at that point of time the order mail has that custom attribute. It seem that the order attribute is saved but the email fires before that.

Also from admin order creation I am not using and observer but I have overwritten Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController but same issues is also arsing on it.

Below are code that i have used:-
config.xml

```
<events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <itemlevelcomment>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Company_ItemlevelComment_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addOrderComment</method>
                    </itemlevelcomment>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
  </events>

 class Company_ItemlevelComment_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function addOrderComment($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order) {
            return $this;
        }
          $orderId = $order->getData('entity_id');
          $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getData('quote_id'));
          $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
          $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
          $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
            foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
                $quoteItemId = $item->getId();
                $itemComment = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($quoteItemId)->getItemComment();

                $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_order_item` SET item_comment = '".$itemComment."' WHERE quote_item_id = ". (int)$quoteItemId." and order_id = " . $orderId;
                $writeConnection->query($query);
            }
    }

}
```

I have also tried with loading object of Mage_Sales_Order_Item and save the object but email is sending without the custom fields.

I have dispalyed the custom attribute on email on following path app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml

```
<?php $comment =$_item->getItemComment(); ?>
                <?php //if(!empty($comment)): ?>
                    <p class="sku"><?php echo $this->__('Comment'); ?>: <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getItemComment()) ?></p>
                <?php //endif; ?>
```

Any thought regarding this?

Comment: Please try `$item->save();` at the end of your foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fieldsets as below:

```
<global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <item_comment>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </item_comment>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_item>
                <item_comment>
                    <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
                    <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                    <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
                </item_comment>
            </sales_convert_order_item>
        </fieldsets>
<global>
```